# How to compile ".c" file for "aarch64" with "cfi" enabled using "clang"?

Tags: clang, sanitization, address-sanitizer

I'm building "main.c" file:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}

int dbl(int x) {
  return x + x;
}

void call_fn(int (*fn)(int)) {
  (*fn)(42);
}

void erase_type(void *fn) {
  call_fn(fn);
}

int main() {
  erase_type(sum);
  return 0;
}
```

for the host "x86" platform with enabled "cfi" sanitizer feature using following command:

```
./clang-8 \
-fsanitize=cfi \
-fvisibility=hidden \
-fno-sanitize-trap=all \
-fuse-ld=gold \
-flto \
main.c \
-o \
main
```

Now I need to compile this file for the "aarch64" processor.
I know how to simply compile this file (with disabled cfi feature).

```
rm -f main.o && \
./clang-8 \
-cc1 \
-triple \
aarch64-funnyos-unknown-gnueabi \
-emit-obj \
-target-cpu \
generic \
-O2 \
-Wall \
-o \
main.o \
-x \
c \
main.c \
&& \
file main.o
```

But I don't know how to compile "main.c" file for "aarch64" with "cfi" enabled.

Does anybody know how to do it?

UPD. Let suppose, that CPU is of ARMv8 type and Linux is running, for example, on QEMU emulator. Let suppose, host is x86 and run on Linux. I need to cross compile code on host x86 Linux for the ARMv8 target (which is run on QEMU, Linux).

Comment: What's the problem compiling with `-fsanitize=cfi`?

Comment: Compiler returns "error: invalid value 'cfi' in '-fsanitize='".

Comment: It returns the same error if  '-fsanitize=' is used with ' -flto'.

Answer (score 0):

Your x86 and AArch64 commands are very different. The first one runs compiler *driver* which supports [compiler flags](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) (`-fsanitize=cfi` in particular).

You second command though runs compiler *proper* (as indicated by `-cc1` switch). This is an internal mode: it's run by compiler driver under the hood so it does not support normal compiler flags and is not meant to be run by ordinary users. You should switch to using compiler driver on AArch64.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Thank you for this information! By the way, is it possible to compile ".c" source file by clang without "-cc1" flag for "aarch64"?

Comment: @lollol Absolutely! Try something like `clang-8 -march=armv8-a --target aarch64-funnyos-unknown-gnueabi ...`.

Comment: I've tried: 
"./clang-8 -emit-llvm -target aarch64 -fsanitize=cfi -flto -fvisibility=hidden -c main.c -o main.bc" and 
"./clang-8 -target aarch64 -fsanitize=cfi -flto -fvisibility=hidden main.bc -o main" 
but last command fails with "error: 'aarch64': unable to pass LLVM bit-code files to linker"...

Comment: @lollol Does it work with `--target=aarch64-linux-gnueabi`? My understanding is that by default linking LLVM IR from linker is unsupported (see [Toolchain.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/228956a75037b98bd4053f5e294a2fee9232f6f4/lib/Driver/ToolChain.cpp#L493)). It works only for selected targets e.g. Linux (see [Linux.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/28d3364fc2f8392c17863e9537f0e441000951d3/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Linux.cpp#L465)) where linker supports LLVM LTO. Note that LTO/bitcodes is a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help me and sorry for such a long delay in response. I've tried "./clang-8 \
--target=aarch64-linux-gnueabi \
-fsanitize=cfi \
-fvisibility=hidden \
-fno-sanitize-trap=all \
-fuse-ld=gold \
-flto \
main.c \
-o \
main"
 
but had no luck. "/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open" a lot of different files like crt1.o, crtbegin.o, libclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-aarch64.a and other.

Comment: @lollol That's probly because your AArch64 toolchain does not include Linux libraries (i.e. it was compiled for different OS). I'm not sure how to help, your OS does not seem to support LTO or at least Clang thinks so. You can try hacking Clang source code to add LTO support (see the links to `Toolchain.cpp` and `Linux.cpp` files I posted above).

Comment: Probably you are right. I haven't found any linker for aarch64, which supports LLVM IR. So, just to generalize current state. It is possible to build .c file using clang for aarch64. It is also possible to use linker, for example, from Android NDK to get binary for aarch64. BUT it is possible only if I'm not using lto with cfi sanitizer. If I enabling them - LLVM IR .o (object) file is produced and no one linker understand it...

Comment: @lollol Could you add more details about your target to the question? E.g. is it GNU-based, what's `funnyos`, etc. Otherwise it's not possible to decide what's needed to enable LTO for it. Note that it's not the CPU (aarch64) that's important here but rather the OS.

Comment: Target is armv8

Comment: I'm sorry for SO saved my edit only after few words :)

@yugr Target is ARMv8, and yes it is GNU-based. Funnyos was choosen by me as an example. It is imaginary name. Let suppose bare metal (with no OS). Also it is interesting for Android OS. I found "android-ndk-r18/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold" but I'm not sure if it supports LLVM's IR object files... Maybe you know? Thank you!

Comment: @lollol Compiler decides whether LTO is supported based on the OS: for Linux targets (Linux or Android) it knows that LTO is supported by linker (see `Linux.cpp` link I posted above). Your `funnyos`/baremetal target probly gets some generic handling which assumes that linker is dumb and can not link LLVM IR object files. As for which toolchain to use (prebuilt Linux AArch64 toolchain, prebuilt Android AArch64 toolchain or in-house) - noone can answer that question except yourself. I suggest to restrain from further discussion in comments and either rephrase your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks one more time for your kind assistance. I agree. Discussion becoming too long and I should go further by myself.

Comment: @lollol No worries. It's totally fine to post more LTO questions, just be sure to provide additional details on your situation, as described above.

Comment: I'm glad. Probably I've found the answer. Following your advice, I've used "--target" option for "clang". Generally it is only first half of what is need to be done, because at this step we'll get intermediate LLVM's code (surprise). Second half (step) is to use gold linker (for example, from Android NDK) with LLVMgold.so plugin (from LLVM), telling linker which emulation mode should be used (in my case "-m aarch64_elf64_le_vec").

Answer (score 0):

At first, we need to compile main.c by clang's compiler into llvm's intermediate code:

```
./clang-8 \
--target=\
aarch64-funnyos-unknown-gnueabi \
-c \
-flto \
-fsanitize=cfi \
-fvisibility=default \
main.c \
-o \
main.o
```

Next step is to translate/link this code into binary file by means of gold linker (for example, from AndroidNDK) using gold plugin (from LLVM project), telling linker the emulation mode (-m option, which means for which architecture the binary should be generated):

```
/PATH/TO/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold \
-pie \
-m \
aarch64_elf64_le_vec \
-o \
main \
-plugin \
/PATH/TO/llvm-project/build/lib/LLVMgold.so \
-plugin-opt=mcpu=generic \
-plugin-opt=O2 \
-plugin-opt=-debugger-tune=gdb \
main.o
```

P.S. Thanks to @yugr for assistance and help!